# Change Background with CSS on particular date?

Tags: css

Does anyone know how to change the background of a website automatically using CSS on specific dates?  Like valentines, easter, xmas etc.

Comment: i upvoted this question because i know it's "just crazy to ask this of CSS"... but i just encountered a use-case scenario and this question came to mind... and under the circumstances it went instantly on my wish list... and then i second guessed it being crazy... with the implementation of containers for example... then i went back to "crazy"... how will the date for the visitor be passed to the CSS given time zones and such? i don't know... still on my wishlist

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use either a server-side language like PHP or JavaScript for this. With PHP, for example, you can access the server date/time with [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and do something like:

```
if(date('m/d') == '2/14'))
    'get your girl a present, dude!';
```

The upside of using server-side code is that it's faster for the user. The disadvantage is that it's your server's date and time, not the user's. So you could do the same thing with Javascript, like so:

```
var curtime = new Date(),
    curday = curtime.getDate(),
    curmonth = curtime.getMonth()+1;

if(curmonth == 2 && curday == 14)
   alert('better be quick');
```

Either way will work.

Added for clarity: The above will allow you to check the day. You can then use that to add a CSS class to your HTML element, for example, which you've prepared for that day. Say you do it with Javascript, you'd write

```
$('#wrap').addClass('valentines');
```

instead of the `alert()` above. This will add the class `valentines` to the `<div id="wrap">` - just as an example. You can then do whatever you like with that CSS class.

Edit: I used [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in the last snippet. You can do it with Javascript alone too - Loktar already added that in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to do it using only css but you could do it combining javascript and css like so,

```
var checkDate=new Date(),
today = new Date();
checkDate.setFullYear(2011,1,14);

if (today.getTime() === checkDate.getTime()){
    document.getElementById("background").className += 'valentinesBackgroundStyle';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sH429/

Comment: Is there a way to check if the date is >= a specific date?

Comment: @AaronFranke something like this should work,

`if (today.getTime() >= checkDate.getTime())`

Using all of the same code above. However I'd opt to use something like moment.js and it's built in methods personally.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with css. You would need to use JavaScript to do it.

For example to change background color to red on valentines day:

```
var date = new Date();
if(date.getDate() == 14 && date.getMonth() == 1) {
    document.body.style.background = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    month = date.getMonth()+1;

if (10 == month && 31 == day) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF9100";
}
```

Notice I added one (1) because the getMonth() method returns the month from 0 to 11 for the specified date, according to local time.