# Change text colour based on date for website

Tags: wordpress, date, text, colors, formula

I have a list of dates in my events page of my website.

I would like the event text to change colour when it IS that date and then change back again when that it's not that date anymore.

I am on wordpress.org

Thanks :)

Comment: do you mean you're hosting your blog on wordpress.com?

Comment: This thread might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701940/change-background-with-css-on-particular-date

Comment: JP LEW - yes i am hosting my blog on wordpress.

Flick - it is relevant but I am not used to that code. Thanks for the link though.